# Update the date in the database with +1 month

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a date column in my users what I want to update with a SQL query

With the SQL query I want to add 1 month to date column in my database.

I now have:

```
UPDATE users SET date=(+ 1 month)
```

When I run this query it is not working. So my question is, how can I make this working?

Comment: What RDBMS do you use?

Comment: Which RDBMS you are using?

Comment: if your are using Mysql then use this function `DATE_ADD(date,INTERVAL expr type)`    http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You never told us the database you are using, so here are several answers:

**MySQL**:

```
UPDATE users
SET date = DATE_ADD(date, INTERVAL 1 month )
```

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE users
SET date = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, date)
```

**Oracle:**

```
UPDATE users
SET date = ADD_MONTHS(date, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**GETDATE()** can be replaced by ur custom date value

```
UPDATE users SET date= DATEADD(month,1,GETDATE())
```

Comment: Is OP your colleague or do you know him in person? If no, then how can you say he is using `SQL Server`?

Comment: just going by his tag when he asked question and a bit of guess combined with bit of common sense :)

Comment: at least I tried and then failed rather than picking someone and wasting time :)

Answer (score 0):

The top-voted answer is good. I will add Postgres here:

**Postgres:**

```
UPDATE users
SET date = date + interval '1 month'
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE [TABLE_NAME]
SET [MY_DATA_FIELD] = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, [MY_DATA_FIELD])
```