# Query to UPDATE only Month in datetime

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in database in which I am storing datetime of an employee, It's basically the Check In and Check Out of employee.

```
2018-11-17 07:22:43.000
2018-11-20 07:18:27.000
2018-11-22 07:28:57.000
2018-11-22 07:00:22.000
2018-11-22 07:24:22.000
```

I want to update the month `11` to `12` without disturbing the rest of data in respective column.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update the date in the database with +1 month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37934137/update-the-date-in-the-database-with-1-month)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following `UPDATE` using [`DATEADD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql):

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = DATEADD(MM, 1, column_name) 
WHERE MONTH(column_name) = 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `DATEADD`:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = DATEADD(MONTH, 1, YourColumn);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
UPDATE YOUR_TABLE 
set YOUR_COLUMN = DATEADD(month, 1, YOUR_COLUMN) 
where MONTH(YOUR_COLUMN) = 11
```